# Building views dynamically and make them reusable as much as possible

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, design-patterns

Let's assume we have a fragment and somewhere along its contents we have a part that is supposed to display X views.
We don't know the X number since it is not fixed.
Each of the X views can completely different. E.g.

```
Separator  
TextView  
Separator  
Linear View with children  
Separator  
TextView  
Separator etc
```

you get the idea.
So I was thinking
1)  should this be build as some kind of custom component? How would I pass the data?
2)   I originally thought this should be an inner fragment but then I thought that I don't care about the activity lifecycle about this.
3)    Another approach is to just have a small function inside my fragment to add these programmatically but then how could I make this reusable?

What is the best strategy on these kind of designs?

Comment: what about `RecyclerView`?

Comment: @pskink:But how can I make it a list if items are completely different per row?

Comment: see `RecyclerView.Adapter#getItemViewType(int position)`

Comment: @pskink:If X is at most 8 is it still a recycler view a good approach?

Comment: no: use a `LinearLayout` for X <= 8, you can wrap it with `ScrollView` if it doesnt fit the screen

Comment: @pskink:Then basically you are in favour of approach (3)? How would I make that reusable? What is the X threshold to figure out if it makes sense to use recycler view?

Comment: well,  i dont know,  if your views take two or more screens i would use RV

Comment: @pskink: So you are in favour of 3 then? How could I make this reusable though?